# GCP cloud sql ERROR: relation "public.heartbeat" does not exist at character 13

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-sql

I'm currently working with terraform for deploying a node js API & the DB on GCP
I need for a spécific env to execute an sql file from a gcp bucket.
Everything was fine for a week, the CI job for used for deploying with terraform was ok.
But now i get this error on the CI :

```
│ Error: local-exec provisioner error
│ 
│   with null_resource.database_eer_run_preprod_dump,
│   on cloudsql.tf line 77, in resource "null_resource" "database_db_run_preprod_sql_file":
│   77:   provisioner "local-exec" {
│ 
│ Error running command 'if [ "qa" = "qa" ];
│ then
│ gcloud sql import sql "cloud-sql-name"
│ gs://path/file.sql --database=db --user=user
│ --impersonate-service-account="terraform@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
│ -q
│ fi
│ ': exit status 1. Output: WARNING: This command is using service account
│ impersonation. All API calls will be executed as
│ [terraform@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com].
│ WARNING: This command is using service account impersonation. All API calls
│ will be executed as
│ [terraform@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com].
│ ERROR: (gcloud.sql.import.sql) HTTPError 403: The service account does not
│ have the required permissions for the bucket.
```

Everything let me think that i did something wrong with the service account permissions or the command for running the sql file from the bucket.
But i didn't change anything and the real difference was here, in the cloud sql logs :

```
{
insertId: "id"
labels: {
INSTANCE_UID: "uid"
LOG_BUCKET_NUM: "55"
}
logName: "projects/projet-name/logs/cloudsql.googleapis.com%2Fpostgres.log"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-12-14T08:49:41.092044870Z"
resource: {
labels: {
database_id: "project-name:cloud-sql-name"
project_id: "project-name"
region: "europe"
}
type: "cloudsql_database"
}
severity: "ERROR"
textPayload: "2023-12-14 08:49:40.262 UTC [27]: [1-1] db=cloudsqladmin,user=cloudsqladmin ERROR:  relation "public.heartbeat" does not exist at character 13"
timestamp: "2023-12-14T08:49:40.262943Z"
}
```

I'm new to terraform and GCP so i try my best to find something about this error and from what i understand the public.heartbeat shoult be created by gcp.

Hope it's clear, my english is really bad sorry in advance.
It's the firt time i ask a question on stack overflow it's new to me please be indulgent

Comment: You have multiple problems. Solve this one first: `The service account does not
have the required permissions for the bucket`. Edit your post and include your Terraform HCL and the service account IAM roles.

Answer (score -1):

**Issue Identified:**

- It appears you are using the `--impersonate-service-account="terraform@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com"` option, but this service account does not have sufficient permissions to execute SQL commands on your SQL database.

**Recommended Actions (perhaps work):**

1. **Create IAM-Based Database User:** Instead of using a traditional username and password, configure an IAM-based database user with the necessary privileges in your current terraform service account if you try run in your code.
2. **Provisioner Limitation:** Check if the `provisioner "local-exec"` in Terraform which can execute SQL in this database. We can try "mysql -u ${var.username} -p${var.my_db_password} -h ${var.my_db.address} < file.sql"